# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory when running Ionic Cordova Platform Add Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic5, wonderpush

I just cant figure out how to solve this problem. I've tried many solutions but nothing works for my case.
So i put my project in `xampp\htdocs` with folder name `exam-ionic`.

Then when i tried to add platform android the error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, 
 open 'c:\xampp\htdocs\exam-ionic\android\package.json'] {
 errno: -4058,
 code: 'ENOENT',
 syscall: 'open',
 path: 'c:/xampp/htdocs/exam-ionic/android/package.json
```

This is when i run `ionic cordova platform add android --verbose`

```
ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 1 functions +2ms
ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 6724: Error: Command 
failed: taskkill /pid 
6724 /T /F
ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "6724" not found.
ionic:utils-process
ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 6724 /T /F'
ionic:utils-process } +916ms
ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: Error: Command 
failed: taskkill /pid 
6724 /T /F
ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "6724" not found.
ionic:utils-process
ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 6724 /T /F'
ionic:utils-process } +3ms
ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 1) +5ms
```

This is my ionic info

```
Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1101.4
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 11.1.4
@angular/cli                  : 11.1.4
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 3.1.0

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.7
@capacitor/core : 2.4.7

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : none
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin- 
ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 9 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : 0.15.3
native-run  : 1.3.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
NodeJS            : v14.16.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm               : 7.9.0
OS                : Windows 10
```

And this is the package.json

```json
{
  "name": "exam-ionic",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.7",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.4.7",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.32.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^5.32.0",
    "@ionic-native/wonderpush": "^5.32.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.1.0",
    "ionic-context-menu": "^5.0.0",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.11.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "wonderpush-cordova-sdk": "^3.0.3",
    "wonderpush-cordova-sdk-fcm": "^1.0.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1101.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.7",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^3.1.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "3.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
      "wonderpush-cordova-sdk": {
        "CLIENT_ID": "a312c22bafed82635f3167cc71a7437a9b840c44",
        "CLIENT_SECRET": "e499dc98a572d63752da6b73494ff8bf3bc99cf04a64bfc5451fbdce52854547"
      },
      "wonderpush-cordova-sdk-fcm": {
        "CLIENT_ID": "a312c22bafed82635f3167cc71a7437a9b840c44",
        "CLIENT_SECRET": "e499dc98a572d63752da6b73494ff8bf3bc99cf04a64bfc5451fbdce52854547",
        "SENDER_ID": "default"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {}
    },
    "platforms": []
  }
}
```

I've tried reinstall the npm, reinstall the cordova, updated the ionic CLI, deleted `node_module` folder + `package.lock.json` then `npm install`, but nothing does work. Please help meeee

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was running with the same error and today I found out the solution.
In the past, I tried a capacitor plugin, but my project is cordova, so I removed it from my project. But I think that some files were not properly deleted and when I ran ionic repair, the problem started.
So, to repair this I deleted the ANDROID folder at project root, any files related to Capacitor at root, edited the package.json and removed everything related with Capacitor and everything works again.

### Solution

1. Delete the `android` folder at project root
2. Edit the `package.json` and remove everything related with `Capacitor`

Answer (score 4):

In my case i had android folder in my root directory which i had copied from the platforms folder. so when i renamed it from android to android-out and ran ionic cordova platfrom add android it worked

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue in android folder. I solved it like : -
My ionic version is 5.4.0

**Run the below commands:**

- ionic cordova platform remove android
- ionic cordova platform add android

Comment: I think you are missing the platform keyword: 

ionic cordova platform rm android

Answer (score 0):

These answers have missed the removal of the 'ios' folder as well. This can be caused by attempting to install via Capacitor when you are still using Cordova. 
*(Generally when you jump between legacy and modern Ionic projects)*

`rm -rf platforms` (to remove all platforms already installed)
`rm -rf ios`
`ionic cordova prepare ios --release --prod` (or android)
Then hit `Y` and it'll re-install ios in accordance with your package.json versioning.

[image: example-of-following-installation]

Comment: @user it’s already represented in text as well

Answer (score 0):

Below Solution works for me:

> Package.json

```
"cordova-android": "^11.0.0",
"cordova-ios": "^6.2.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^7.0.1",
"@ionic/cordova-builders": "^9.0.0",
```

> Perform the below steps in your root terminal:

- Remove (android | ios ) platform - `ionic cordova platform remove (android | ios)`
- Install Resouce package - `npm i -g cordova-res  && ionic cordova resources (android | ios) --force`
- Add platform again - `ionic cordova platform build (android | ios)`